# Redirect visitor to their language based on Cloudflare GEO TARGET

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation, cloudflare, geo

I’m reading out through a lot of tutorials and different websites, although I’m not a programmer, I tried my best, as I’m sure it can be done, but I’m on a dead end.

I’m trying to use the HTTP header that Cloudflare sends ["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]); to redirect the user to its country. I need to be able to send multiple locations to same country (Mexico, Spain, Colombia.... to mysite.com/es/) and i need to be able to create multiple rules (so send Spanish speakers to mysite.com/es and German speakers to mysite.com/de/ and if not set, then redirect to main site mysite.com). It should be just necessary to create a redirection from the home page (mysite.com).

Would anyone help me doing so on the functions.php file or any other method? I tried looking for a plugin as well… I’m really surprised no one, not even Cloudflare put this on a plugin.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is not default functionality within your Cloudflare account, but it can be accomplished with some tinkering on your server. [This discussion](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/redirecting-specific-country-to-sub-domain/12688) has details that might be helpful to review.

Also, this is something that should be pretty easy to accomplish with a [Cloudflare Worker](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-workers/), but you would need some programming chops to try that.

Comment: It it a default functionality, as i have acomplished already with just one language (ES) and it worked fine but using .htaccess